# Session in Next.js not returning the correct values

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt, next-auth

After login in, some of the data returned does not show up on the session, it only returns the email, name.
The ID however goes under the user object. Also, I have console.log(user.data) which returns the user perfectly with all those attributes.

**[...nextauth].js**

```
      async authorize(credentials) {
    const user = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/login", {
      email: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password,
    });

    console.log(user.data);
 //{
//  user: {
//    id: 1,
//    name: 'admin',
//    surname: 'surname admin',
//   email: 'admin@email.com',
//    avatar: null,
//    role: '1',
//    dob: '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
//    description: null,
//    cv: null,
//    createdAt: '2022-01-07T00:03:09.000Z',
//    updatedAt: '2022-01-07T00:03:09.000Z'
//  }
//}
//


    if (user.data.message === "User not found") {
      return null;
    }

    if (user.data.user) {
      return {
        id: user.data.user.id, //suppose to be 1
        name: user.data.user.name, //suppose to be admin
        surname: user.data.user.surname, //suppose to be surname
        email: user.data.user.email, //suppose to be admin@email.com
      };
    }
  },
```

**index.js**

```
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  console.log(session);
// OUTPUT:
// expires: "2022-02-18T08:55:39.898Z"
// id: 1
// user: {name: 'admin', email: 'admin@email.com'}
```

Comment: @Daniel useSession() is created by NextJS.

Comment: and where is the `authorize` function called? I can't see the connection between the files

Comment: @Daniel, It is called in the [...nextauth].js file, if you are familiar with NextJS, this fetch from an API and then user can log in.
Here for more details: https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials

Comment: Have you tried using the [`jwt`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) and [`session`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback) callbacks to pass the extra values you want?

Comment: which version of the next-auth are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to pass all the values in the callback and it will work.
Passing all the token values to the session object

```
  callbacks: {
jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
  if (user) {
    token.id = user.id;
    token.name = user.name;
    token.surname = user.surname;
    token.email = user.email;

  }
  return token;
},
session: ({ session, token }) => {
  if (token) {
    session.id = token.id;
    session.name = token.name;
    session.surname = token.surname;
    session.email = token.email;
  }
  return session;
},
```

},

Answer (score 3):

Try adding something like this inside of NextAuth option

```
callbacks: {
  async session({ session, token }) {
    session.user = token.user;
    return session;
  },
  async jwt({ token, user }) {
    if (user) {
      token.user = user;
    }
    return token;
  },
},
```

Comment: this is the correct answer -- you need to use the session callback to select what data should be available in the browser